# Don't show home page in the navigation menu on Django CMS

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I have a Django CMS site, and I want to display every page in the navigation menu, except for the home page, because it'll have a separate link elsewhere. How can I do it?

The pages I have are separated, no subpages or stuff like that.

And I'm currently displaying the menu using the `show_menu` tag.

Thanks.

Comment: You might need to override the [default menu template](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/menus/templates/menu/menu.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can uncheck the menu checkbox in the pages panel.

[image: menu unchecked djangocms]